# Problems with linking and AzureMobileServices in release mode on Android

Tags: android, msbuild, linker, xamarin

In my Android project i use AzureMobileServices, but when i start it in release it throws a NullReferenceException somewere deep in AMS.

As i understand this problem related to linking some Sdk assemblies, and also i can remove this problem by disable linking at all. But this will increase app size and it's big enough

Here is stack trace

```
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480): Parameter name: method
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure, Boolean allowClosed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
An unhandled exception occured.

08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.CreateLambda (System.Type delegateType, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.String name, Boolean tailCall, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.PartialEvaluator+<>c__DisplayClass4.<EvaluateIndependentSubtrees>b__3 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Func`2 recur) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary (System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression b) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression exp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.<>n__FabricatedMethod4 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.<Visit>b__3 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.PartialEvaluator+<>c__DisplayClass4.<EvaluateIndependentSubtrees>b__3 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Func`2 recur) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda (System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression lambda) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression exp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.<>n__FabricatedMethod4 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.<Visit>b__3 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.PartialEvaluator+<>c__DisplayClass4.<EvaluateIndependentSubtrees>b__3 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Func`2 recur) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary (System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression u) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression exp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.298 I/MonoDroid(24480):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.<>n__FabricatedMethod4 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression ) [0x00000] 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480): 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480): Unhandled Exception:
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480): System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480): Parameter name: method
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure, Boolean allowClosed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.CreateLambda (System.Type delegateType, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.String name, Boolean tailCall, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono    (24480):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename un
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono-rt (24480): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono-rt (24480): Parameter name: method
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono-rt (24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure, Boolean allowClosed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono-rt (24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono-rt (24480):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono-rt (24480):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.CreateLambda (System.Type delegateType, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.String name, Boolean tailCall, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-14 03:07:13.928 E/mono-rt (24480):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in
```

I read an [official xamarin topic about linking](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/) and [MSBuild AndroidLinkSkip](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/#Linking).
I added this assemblies to skip tag `System.Linq;System.Reflection;Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext` but this does not help at all.

here is a part of proj file

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>SdkOnly</AndroidLinkMode>
    <AndroidLinkSkip>System.Linq;System.Reflection;Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext</AndroidLinkSkip>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have no idea what else i should add to fix the problem. Probably i will try to add **all assemblies** and see will it help. Meantime, can anyone give me any advice what i should add to link skip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem, and i had to skip a gang of assemblies until it worked properly.
These are the assemblies i skip when linking: (My project is called MvvMAppiAppi by the way )

- Mono.Android;System;
- System.Core;
- System.Net.Http;
- System.Xml;
- MvvMAppiAppi.Droid;
- MvvMAppiAppi.Core;
- MvvMAppiAppi.AzureSvc;
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile;
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext;
- Newtonsoft.Json;

Only then did the linking work. I would indeed add assemblies, and see how much you need to skip until it compiles... I don't think there is another way around.

Comment: That was System.Core for me. Thank you!